# Moment.js: get the day of the year from date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I get the day of the year from 2022-01-03 by using Momentjs?

Comment: What do you mean by "day of the year"? Do you mean "day of the week", or days from New Year's Day?

Comment: Their documentation is pretty exhaustive. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dayOfYear`:

```js
const day = moment('2022-01-03').dayOfYear();

console.log(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```